# Javascript proxy-pattern problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like that:

```
// original function
Foo = function(params) {
  do foo...
}
Foo.prototype.alert = function() {
  alert('foo');
}
```

Now i want to interfere:

```
Bar = Foo;
Foo = function(params) {
  do bar...
  return Foo(params);
}
```

Or the JQuery way:

```
(function() {
  var proxied = Foo;
  Foo = function() {
    do bar...
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

The problem now is that Foo is missing all its prototype methods. Any idea how I could make this work?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `return Bar(params);` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.extend(Foo.prototype, proxied.prototype);
```

Or even:

```
Foo.prototype = proxied.prototype;
```